# Find a $4\times 3$ matrix to make a $3 \times 4$ matrix invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

The  matrix $P$ is 3x4 given. Is there a 4x3 matrix $Q$ such that the product of $QP$ is invertible? If this can't happen can someone explain why?Thanks.

[Matrix P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScFY3.png)

Comment: do you know what the rank of a matrix is?

Comment: the rank of P is 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this website and can't add a comment just yet but you're question and description don't match. The title asks to find a $3 \times 4$ matrix but your Q matrix has dimension $4 \times 3$.

Broadly, if you want a $Q_{4 \times 3} \times P_{3 \times 4}$ matrix to be invertible, that is impossible. Look at [Can the product of an $4\times 3$ matrix and a $3\times 4$ matrix be invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410599/can-the-product-of-an-4-times-3-matrix-and-a-3-times-4-matrix-be-invertible/1410608#1410608).

Next, if you want a $Q_{3 \times 4} \times P_{4 \times 3}$ matrix to be invertible, that is also not directly guaranteed. You need your P matrix to have rank 3, for starters. This is not satisfied in your example at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScFY3.png, where P has rank 2, and so there is no Q whose multiplication in any direction makes their product invertible.